# Why the below code is not executing for every value of i in for loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

**SetTimeout** is not working for each i of for loop. I've tried almost everything, used promise, etc but nothing is working.

```
animateDijkstra(visitedNodesInOrder) {
  for (let i = 0; i < visitedNodesInOrder.length; i++) {
    // here set timeout is not working for each i :(
    setTimeout(() => {
      const node = visitedNodesInOrder[i];
      const newGrid = this.state.grid.slice();
      const newNode = {
        ...node,
        isVisited: true,
      };
      newGrid[node.row][node.col] = newNode;
      this.setState({ grid: newGrid });
    }, 3000 * (i + 1));
  }
};
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve] -> _"**Describe the problem**. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Answer (score 0):

```
animateDijkstra(visitedNodesInOrder) {
for (let i = 0; i < visitedNodesInOrder.length; i++) {
    // here set timeout is not working for each i :(

    (function() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const loopVariable = i;
            const node = visitedNodesInOrder[loopVariable];
            const newGrid = this.state.grid.slice();
            const newNode = {
                ...node,
                isVisited: true,
            };
            newGrid[node.row][node.col] = newNode;
            this.setState({
                grid: newGrid
            });
        }, 3000 * (loopVariable + 1));
    })()
}
};
```